# how to use if statement in ng repeat using angular 1.0.8

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My angular is 1.0.8-stable

My objective is to display data in rows of 3.

My html should look like

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item">item2</div>
    <div class="item">item3</div>
</div>
```

My pseudo code is if the $index mod 3 == 0 then I will display `<div class="table-row">`.

if the $index mod 3 == 2, then I will display `</div>`.

So far, I have this.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in my_works.items'>
    <!-- if index mod 3 == 0 show <div>-->
    <!-- if index mod 3 == 2 show </div>-->
</div>
```

Perhaps I was thinking it in the wrong way as there may be a more efficient way to do this in angularjs?

Comment: first of all, there's `ngIf` , second of all - you're not the first person trying to show elements in rows of 3. Search SO for relevant questions :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you. But I am using the stable 1.0.8 so no ngIf for me. I have searched SO, so far no questions that have the same setup as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use `ng-if` in 1.0.8 here are two variations that solve the problem.  They both wrap 3 items into a table-row `div`

The outer loop counts off in groups of three, so it fires once per outer table-row `div`.  The second approach uses a filter to control the loop range but it should have better performance.  The first approach doesn't require a new filter.

Then the inner `ng-repeat` loops through the 3 items within a row.  It uses slice to get just the 3 array items needed for that particular row.

Here's a fiddle with both of the variations working:  http://jsfiddle.net/f8D8q/4/

**Option 1:** Solution without a new filter:

```
   <div ng-repeat='itemtmp in items|limitTo:(items.length/3)+1'>
        <div class="table-row"> 
            <span ng-repeat='item in items.slice($index*3,($index*3+3))'>
              {{item.name}} - {{$index}}
            </span>
          </div>
   </div>
```

**Option 2:** More performant solution using range filter from http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#more-about-loops

```
   <div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:(items.length/3)+1">
        <div class="table-row">
            <span ng-repeat='item in items.slice($index*3,($index*3+3))'>
                {{item.name}} - {{$index}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the associated range filter:

```
 app.filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            input.push(i);
        }
        return input;
    };
});
```

Both are tested (down to 1.0.2) and work.

Comment: I pick this answer and option 2. This is an excellent answer. I don't understand why it got -1 vote.

Comment: I have another issue with sending jsonp requests from angularjs. Care to help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19603757/80353

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(key, value) in expression` – where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.

You can try something like this

```
<div ng-repeat='(index, item) in my_works.items'> 
   <div class="table-row" ng-show="index % 3 == 0">
   </div>
</div>
```

[Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)

Comment: Note that `ng-show` will hide the entire div (including contents).  So you can't use it to create just the opening part of the div.  It'd be nice to have this level of control.  But sadly we don't- so this answer just hides every third item

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your flat list of items to a list of lists of 3 items.
2. Iterate over the list of lists.

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="list in listOfLists">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in list">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

If you already have a list, `items`, you could add a filter `chunked` and replace `listOfLists` with `items|chunked:3`, assuming you implement `chunked` something like this:

```
app.filter('chunked', function(){
    return function(list, chunkSize){
        var chunks = [];
        angular.forEach(list, function(element, i){
            if(i % chunkSize === 0){
                 currentChunk = [];
                 chunks.push(currentChunk);
            }
            currentChunk.push(element);
        });
        return chunks;
    };
});
```

I think that matches what you are trying to do; here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3h7JprbXFVwnNZErj7hl

I didn't get a chance to test with old Angular though.

Comment: This caused "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" for me.