# how to change the headers for angularjs $http.jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-headers

I read the [document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

but I think I must have misunderstood it.

```
$http.defaults.headers.jsonp = { 'Accept' : 'application/json'};
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
```

I also have tried

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.jsonp = { 'Accept' : 'application/json'};
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
```

I wanted to change the `Accept` to `application/json`

Neither work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to control headers sent by a browser while using JSONP. JSONP is a smart trick (or a hack, depending on how you see it...) that consist of inserting a `<script>` tag pointing to a server endpoint. Ultimately it is a browser who will decide which headers to sent while requesting scripts via `<script>` tag and you can't influence it.

More info here: [Modify HTTP Headers for a JSONP request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350778/1418796)

Comment: so essentially you are saying it is not possible to change the headers for jsonp request. THank you.