# AngularJS ngResource not sending custom header

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I'm attempting to use ngResource to query a REST API. I need to specify my API key in a custom header. I've tried it like so:

```
angular.module('ApiService', ['ngResource'])

  .factory('Api', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    this.apiEndpoint = '';
    this.apiKey = '';

    return {

      init: function(apiEndpoint, apiKey) {
        this.apiEndpoint = apiEndpoint;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
      },

      get: function(collection) {
        return $resource(this.apiEndpoint + 'api/1/' + collection, {},
          {
            get: {
              method: 'JSONP',
              headers: {'api_key': this.apiKey},
              params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}
            }
          }
        ).get();
      }

    };

  }]);
```

which I then use in my controller like:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, Api, ENV) {
  Api.init(ENV.apiEndpoint, ENV.apiKey);
  var widgets = Api.get('widgets');
});
```

My custom header isn't set when I inspect the XHR. Also, why will the XHR not run until I call an empty `.get()` after the initial `$resource:get()` method?

I've also tried to set the headers in `$httpResource` directly:

```
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get  = {'api_key': 'abc123'};
  })
```

but this still doesn't set the custom header when I inspect the network request. What am I missing?

Comment: You use JSONP as method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the headers for angularjs $http.jsonp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603757/how-to-change-the-headers-for-angularjs-http-jsonp)

Comment: @maxdec I think you're right. Since this for whatever reason has gotten a little bit of attention in the past 24 hours, I'll post that as the answer and crosslink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is, of course, that I was using JSONP in this request, which doesn't include the ability to craft headers when making a request. See [how to change the headers for angularjs $http.jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603757/how-to-change-the-headers-for-angularjs-http-jsonp).

Specifically, JSONP simply includes a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the DOM to load cross-domain javascript, so it's up to your browser to send the default headers.